# OSGI integration with Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, osgi

Currently I am developing an OSGI application to abstract a frontend UI over some backend services. The architecture of the backend is traditional Java EE running in jboss application servers.

In the frontend application I have a need to retrieve some data from the backend (ultimately it's database data) but there are some EJBs that can be used to retrieve the data.

Based on some reading I have done it doesn't appear to be very easy, and not doable without using the servlet bridge, to invoke an EJB from within the OSGI container.

I had some thoughts about wrapping these in a web service, but am not sure on what the best approach may be. I would like some thoughts on best practices or approaches to integrating OSGI with Java EE as far as data interaction would go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an application that uses this method via [Spring remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) (Section 19.4 in our case).

It is simple to create a service interface that has a remote invocation bundle on the client, and direct access to the EJB on the server.  It also has the nicety of having no dependencies to the server specific code.

Comment: This sounds more along the lines of what I would like to do.  Could you explain more how you do this?  It sounds like you have an osgi bundle that invokes the servlet(running in a spring app i'm guessing) and from within the servlet you are accessing your ejb?  Am I correct in this?

Comment: I will accept this answer as it led me to thoughts on my current solution.  I provided a service interface that makes webservice calls to and endpoint wrapping my existing ejbs.

Comment: @broschb - You are mostly correct in your first comment.  The servlet is in fact the Spring DispatcherServlet and we wire in the EJB to be called via the servlet.  Then the client end simply uses the HttpInvoker code provided by Spring to create a dynamic proxy which will make the calls to the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using JBoss version 4.3.x - you should be able to wrap the jbossall-client.jar and then use the org.jboss.remoting.InvokerLocator to create a org.jboss.remoting.Client - this will allow you to do anything but is rather heavyweight (the jar is 4.7mb).  Another option would be access the JNDI of the JBoss instance.

Either way you'll (obviously) need the EJB definitions available to your OSGi app.